# Indent pagenotes with multiple lines in memoir

Tags: indentation, memoir, endnotes

I'm writing a non fiction book using the `memoir` package.

I've been playing around quite a lot, and I must say I'm very satisfied with [Peter Wilson's guide](http://wwwcdf.pd.infn.it/localdoc/memman.pdf).

`Pagenotes` are great because they allow me to have all notes at the end of the book, divided by chapter, with continuos numbering.

There is one thing though I can't seem to find: how to change the indentation of  multiples lines in the endnotes (so that the text of the the second and successive lines is aligned with the text of the first line, not with the note number).

With normal footnotes I could do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

How do I achieve the same result with pagenotes?

Comment: Your posting is a bit confusing: You say that you use the `memoir` document class, yet the MWE uses the `article` document class and the `scrextend` package. What gives?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer:**

My first alternative thought was to set `\hangindent` to a suitable value but since you mentioned that you have lists in the notes I propose using a list for formatting. This seems a bit improvised, though:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\prenotetext{%
  \list{}{%
    \setlength\leftmargin{2.5em}%
    \setlength\topsep{-\baselineskip}}
  \item}
\renewcommand*\postnotetext{\endlist\bigskip\medskip}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\idtextinnotes[1]{#1.\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*\notenuminnotes[1]{#1.\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

\makepagenote

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
This is some arbitrary\pagenote{%
 \lipsum[1]
 \begin{itemize}
   \item bla
   \item blub
 \end{itemize}
 \lipsum[2]} text.

This is some arbitrary\pagenote[123]{\lipsum[1-2]} text.

\printpagenotes*
\end{document}
```

**Original answer:**

Do you mean something like this? This will prevent pagebreaks in a note, though...

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% redefine \prenotetext and \postnotetext:
\renewcommand*\prenotetext{\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5em}}
\renewcommand*\postnotetext{\end{minipage}\medskip}

% only that we can see how large note numbers look:
\renewcommand*\idtextinnotes[1]{#1.\space}

\makepagenote
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
This is some arbitrary\pagenote{\lipsum[1]} text.

This is some arbitrary\pagenote[123]{\lipsum[1]} text.

\printpagenotes*
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I am looking for, but I need pagebreaks on the notes. In fact, I even have some itemized lists, so the code above does not compile on my book :(

Comment: @4v4l0n42 see updated answer.

Comment: @4v4l0n42 Did the updated version work for you?

Comment: Yes, and no.
Other problems arose, most likely because I need to fix other things as well. Thank you for the answer, I'll work in it, and if I can't solve it I'll get back with more questions :)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach, just for posterity. My criteria was:

- Each item starts with a page number, right-justified at a fixed position.
- If the note occurred within a footnote, then the page number is followed by the footnote number, formatted as a superscript.
- The footnote number (if any) is in a left-justified box; IOW, footnote numbers consume a variable portion of the fixed gutter between the page number and the page note text.
- The first paragraph is not indented; any additional paragraphs are.

The latter requirement is easily fulfilled by putting a `\noindent` inside the redefined `\prenoteinnotes`. I originally went with a `\hangindent` in there, but of course, that did not provide proper indentation for things like (the somewhat rare) additional paragraphs, bullet lists, etc. I then tried to fix this with `\adjustwidth` wrapping just the text, which blew up rather badly for reasons I didn't figure out. My final solution was to wrap everything in each item in `\adjustwidth`, while also shoving my boxes that precede the item text back to their original left margin with a negative `\hspace`. The relevant bits (machinations to deliver page/footnote numbers not shown/described) looked like this:

```
\renewcommand{\prenoteinnotes}{%
    \small\par\noindent%
    }%
\renewcommand{\noteidinnotes}[2]{% {notenum}{id}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{33pt}{0pt}%
        \hspace{-33pt}\makebox[30pt][l]{%
            \makebox[16pt][r]{\pageref{#2}}%
            \makebox[14pt][l]{\ifnum#1>0\textsuperscript{#1}\fi%
            }%
    }%
}%
\renewcommand{\pageinnotes}[1]{}%
\renewcommand{\postnotetext}{%
    \end{adjustwidth}%
}%
\renewcommand{\postnoteinnotes}{\par}%
```

This seems to handle the few hundred cases I've thrown at it so far, and ends up looking like:

[image: sample page from end notes]